# Не хочу [обучение], хочу быть сыном олигарха

Tags: предложение, удаление-метки

Зачем нужна метка [обучение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) ?

Все вопросы на SO так или иначе сводятся к обучению или познанию информации для своего развития. А простые разговоры об — оффтоп.

Предлагаю <s>свергнуть</s> удалить и забыть как страшный сон и оффтоп.

Comment: Раз уж снимаете массово метку - ставьте на вопросы тревогу для модератора, а то на выходе получается куча untagged мусора

Comment: @PashaPash ммм. хорошо. а может быть подскажите тогда своё решение, которое вы будете применять? и разве untagged не является мусором по умолчанию?

Comment: Заплюсованные условно-хорошие вопросы - оставить как есть. с <=0 голосов, закрытые и без ответов - сжечь.

Comment: @PashaPash не совсем понял, если условно-хорошие вопросы, то метка остается? или вопрос остается, но повесится другая какая-либо подходящая метка? правильно ли я понимаю, что тревогу для модератора можно оставлять только там, где изначально одна метка, а если есть другие, то можно просто снять?

Comment: Вопрос остается, и на него стоит повесить хоть какую-то метку (иначе это какой-то вопрос-оффтоп, для которого даже метки не нашлось). Тревоги стоит ставить на условно-плохие вопросы (те, которые хотелось бы сжечь)

Comment: по-моему метка "обучение" имеет место быть исходя из того, что есть учебные задачи, задачи олимпиад, на каких-то сайтах и тд. т.е. сам вопрошающий уже сразу говорит о том, что вопрос связан с учебой. Именно для таких вот вопросов оставить эту метку. Кто будет искать по этой метке? ... так такой же студент или преподаватель, которые хотят проверить, что есть на форуме по данной тематике. Может студент не сам решил, а ему тут решили.

Comment: @Volk но вопросы по обучению могут быть совершенно по разным сферам программирования. К тому же, аналогичную метку [учебное-задание] выпили и по всей сети, и на некоторых сайтах даже запретили

Comment: @Зонтик, если речь идет о том, чтобы вообще убрать метку, это одна ситуация. Если же у нас остается метка, то тогда её ставить на вопросы в которых упоминается, что они являются учебными будет логично.

Comment: @Volk речь давно уже ни о чём не идёт. Вопрос шестилетней давности. Смысла обсуждения этого уже нет давно

Comment: @Volk + Не надо поднимать старые вопросы, добавляя метку [обучение] и другие сомнительные метки. Вы ее добавляете в том числе туда, где она уже была удалена: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/17345/revisions

Comment: Каждый раз будут приходить новые пользователи и придется с ними проводить некую разъяснительную работу, если метка будет существовать. Больше применять данную метку не буду.

Comment: @Volk, если просто метка существует, это еще не значит что ее добавлять в вопросы. Особенно, если она фактически подходит к 90% вопросов (метаметки). Метки языков программирования, фреймворков, технологий, другие конкретные метки — полезны, они позволяют быстро понять о чем вопрос, не открывая его. Метаметки (как "обучение", "числа", "строки" и прочее) - в целом довольно бесполезны.

Comment: В итоге по данной метке осталось 3 вопроса. Но заменить на что-то другое там проблематично, разве что вопросы сами удалить, т.к. они изначально слишком широкие и оффтопичные.

Comment: Все, метки больше нет

Answer (score 0):

Чисто формально предположу, что метка может быть полезна для студентов/учеников и преподавателей. Т.е. с её помощью можно выделять вопросы, затрагиваемые в учебных заведениях. Здесь, правда, есть нюанс, что уровень обучения далеко не везде одинаковый, и таким образом можно встретить как элементарные вопросы, так и вопросы повышенной сложности. Более того, кто-то может заниматься *самообучением* и решать совершенно разные задачи.

На большом SO нашёл метку [**self-learning**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-learning), которая вроде бы является синонимом для **self-improvement** (это можно заметить, если перейти по ссылке). Однако она тоже какая-то особенная:

> [image: invalid tag]

Надо бы уточнить этот механизм, и может быть использовать его у нас для запрета нежелательных меток вместо описания вида "НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ ЭТУ МЕТКУ АТАТА!".