# Стоит ли нам взять пример с "Русского языка" и ввести [недопустимую-метку]?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, создание-метки

#### Интересная практика с другого сайта сети `StackExchange`

На втором русскоязычном сайте сети `StackExchange` ([Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/)) столкнулись с проблемой: время от времени появляются бесполезные метки (что-то вроде [русский-язык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba), [русский](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9), [слово](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be), [л-толстой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9) и другие). Они могут быть прикреплены к 90% вопросов, либо просто не показывают, о чём вопрос. Да, такие метки можно выпилить, путём открепления их от всех вопросов с этой меткой. **Но такие метки создаются снова!**

Проблему решили так: [ввели метку [недопустимая-метка]](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/241/) и сделали все эти бессмысленые метки синонимами [недопустимая-метка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0).

Плюсы такого решения:

- Это можно сделать руками, для этого не нужно изменения функционала;
- Таким образом метки не могут "воскреснуть".

#### Что я хочу предложить и обсудить

Стоит ли нам перенять эту практику с "Русского языка"? Кстати, эта идея пришла мне в голову после [этого поста](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12711/12712#12712).

И первые кандидаты на недопустимость:

- [интернет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82) (самая большая помойка, 200 вопросов) - [обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10484/);
- [работа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0) (81 вопрос);
- [проверка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0) (81 вопрос) - [обсуждение на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7339/);
- [информатика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0) (79 вопросов) - [обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6125/);
- [обучение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) (70 вопросов, есть свежие) - [обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5800/);
- [software](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software) (11 вопросов, обсуждение [раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7041/) и [два](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4338/), вроде уже выпиливали, но воскресла);
- [разработка-по](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be) (9 вопросов);
- [разработка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0) (пока нет вопросов, но [второй раз уже выпиливаем!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12711/));
- [фриланс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81) (пока нет вопросов, но второй раз уже выпиливаем);
- [Ещё пара таких меток](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320/);
- И многие другие.... (чтобы дополнить список, можно пройтись по [удаление-метки](/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8))

Comment: Если честно не особо понимаю этого беспокойства по поводу бесполезных меток. Ну налепил кто-то бесполезную метку на вопрос и налепил, не пользуйтесь ей и всё, или удалите с вопроса правкой если глаза прям мозолит о_О Как по мне - информационного шума от подобных вопросов на мете чуть ли не больше, чем от самих мусорных меток

Comment: Интересная идея. Но так же интересно, что на РЯ около трёх сотен вопросов существует с этой меткой (и синонимами). Заодно предлагаю ознакомиться с тем, когда следует использовать [внутристрочное выделение кода](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1328/176217).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ "около трёх сотен", на самом деле 168 =)

Comment: [276](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mKOL.jpg)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ у вас видимо удалённые вопросы отображаются. А "живых" вопросов - 168: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEbIC.png И я проверил, это не "цитируемые".

Comment: Нет, я там не модератор, чтобы мне удалённые показывались. При переключении с "новые" на "текущие" кол-во меняется. То ли бага, то ли какая-то особенность. [Опубликовал на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389161/339911).

Comment: @yolosora предлагаемое нововведение - попытка закончить беспокойство по поводу вредных меток.

Comment: В принципе озвученная проблема решается сжиганием меток, какой-то специальную метку добавлять не нужно (тем более что как раз она проблему не решает).

Comment: @Зонтик а что значит "вредная метка"? Я, как автор вопроса, могу считать, что метка даже очень полезная, например как [смоленск](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12338/191482)  .... К тому же содание темы на каждую из 100500 меток "что это за метка?" на мете - добавляет новую проблему: замусоривание Меты ненужными бесполезными темами

Comment: @Зонтик а если учитывать то, что [Для создания новой метки достаточно иметь 300 реп.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12712/191482) то тогда что процесс "беспокойства о вредных метках" будет бесконечным

Comment: соглашусь, что я раньше не замечал этих самых "вредных меток", кроме откровенно [хамских](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12170/209304). Зачем эта борьба, тоже не понятно. Сейчас же, каждый второй/третий вопрос на Мете про метки, причем с кликбейтными темами по типу [Надо же, разработка воскресла!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12711/209304). Бесполезно и раздражающе (мнение)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Мое мнение: добавление какой-то специальной метки, на которую будут синонимизированы какие-то раздражающие метки не решает проблемы раздражающих меток - вместо нескольких разных меток будет появляться одна раздражающая [недопустимая-метка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0), которую все равно вручную нужно будет удалять.

Проблема постоянно удаляемых и опять возникающих меток решается сжиганием меток (полным уничтожением без возможности снова создать), что могут делать модераторы. При этом для синонимизации опять же нужно обращаться к модераторам, проще сразу просить сжечь метку, чем синонимизировать, а потом постоянно вручную удалять `[недопустимую-метку]`

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0

Comment: @Зонтик я знаю когда нужно или не нужно использовать внутристрочное выделение кодом. В данном случае оно вполне уместно.

Comment: Просто есть такая вещь, как ссылка на метку, я имею в виду оформление `[tag:название-метки]`

Comment: @Зонтик не имеет смысла оформлять как метку название не существующей метки (примерно столько же смысла, как давать ссылку на несуществующую страницу). Про `[tag:...]` я в курсе.

Comment: @Зонтик я передумал, в первом случае переделал через tag, во втором случае оставил как было, потому что без склонения будет криво выглядеть.